# Type inference in MaybeMonad

Tags: c#, monads

I'm trying out an example from this [site](https://mikhail.io/2016/01/monads-explained-in-csharp/) but running into following inference problem.

The example is about maybe Monads and saves from continuous null checking and write code in a linear fashion.

> The type arguments for method `Maybe<Customer>.Bind<TO>(Func<Customer,
>   Maybe<TO>>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the
>   type arguments explicitly.

**Maybe.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Monads
{
    public class Maybe<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly T value;

        public Maybe(T someValue) 
        {
            if(someValue == null) 
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someValue));
            this.value = someValue;
        }

        private Maybe(){}

        public Maybe<TO> Bind<TO>(Func<T, Maybe<TO>> func) where TO : class
        {
            return value != null ? func(value) : Maybe<TO>.None();
        }

        public static Maybe<T> None() => new Maybe<T>();
    }
}
```

**IMonadicRepository**

```
namespace Monads
{
    public interface IMonadicRepository
    {
       Maybe<Customer> GetCustomer(int id);
       Maybe<Address> GetAddress(int id);
    }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
namespace Monads {
    public class Repository : IMonadicRepository
    {
        public Maybe<Customer> GetCustomer(int id) {
            return new Maybe<Customer>(new Customer(id));
        }

        public Maybe<Address> GetAddress(int id)
        {
            return new Maybe<Address>(new Address(id));
        }
    }
}
```

**Customer.cs**

```
namespace Monads
{
    public class Customer 
    {
        public Customer(int id) {
        }

        public Address Address {get; set;}
    }
}
```

**Address.cs**

```
namespace Monads 
{
    public class Address 
    {
        public Address(int id) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage - Programs.cs**

```
namespace Monads
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IMonadicRepository repository = new Repository();
            repository.GetCustomer(1)
                .Bind(customer => customer.Address); // error
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**: The type arguments for method `'Maybe.Bind(Func>)'` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: If you read comments to the linked post - you may read that OP explains he assumed `Address` property in `Customer` class (and other similar properties) are of type `Maybe<Address>`.

Comment: And if you want to learn more about monads (with examples in C#) - I'd suggest to read Eric Lippert series about monads: https://ericlippert.com/category/monads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in `.Bind(customer => customer.Address)` line, `customer.Address` is of type `Address`. The function `Bind`, however, requires a lambda that returns a `Maybe<Address>`, not an `Address`.

I'm not sure if that is the right approach, but one option is to use the `Return` extension method defined in the post:

```
repository.GetCustomer(1)
    .Bind(c => c.Address.Return());
```

For completion, I'll copy it here as well:

```
public static class MaybeExtensions
{
    public static Maybe<T> Return<T>(this T value) where T : class
    {
        return value != null ? new Maybe<T>(value) : Maybe<T>.None();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for adding the MaybeExtensions, I'm wondering why did he use `repo.GetCustomer(customerId)
        .Bind(c => c.Address)` without return, what part am I missing in my implementation that's causing mismatch in the chain of the calls. The code is incomplete and abstract from his site and I filled in details myself for the actors, may be I did wrong something with actors of the system above like `Customer` and `Address`

Comment: I think I got the mistake, my getter in the Customer class should be
 `public Maybe<Address> Address {get; set;}`

Comment: @App2015 - Right, the post also has another version of the repository, so maybe there are also another model - but should the model include a maybe directly? Also, wouldn't that would mean the line `.Bind(a => repo.GetAddress(a.Id))` wouldn't work - because now `a` is a `Maybe<Address>, which doesn't have an `Id`.

Comment: @App2015 - Another option is `repository.GetCustomer(1).Bind(a => repository.GetAddress(a.Address.Id))`, but then we never handle a `null` Address. I'm probably missing something, because mondas never clicked for me (yet?).

Comment: I never got it either, until I learned F# and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srQt1NAHYC0 then it all made sense. Now applying learned skills in C# but it's just one part, https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad has a lot more

Comment: with respect to `repo.GetAddress(a.Id)`, I just didn't have the field in my class, I'm adding fields as I'm learning his approach but getting there, would have been easier if he provided a complete example on github